# Windows Cluster unable to failover

Tags: networking, failovercluster, windows-cluster

I need help on an issue I just found on a Windows Server 2016 cluster of two nodes, Server A in network 192.168.10., the other node, Server B on a different network, 192.168.20.

All the resources (six resources with a cluster IP address) are hosted on the Server A.

I was schedule to patch server A, and thus, tried to failover all resources to server B, but they all failed. So I checked that all the IPs that are on the Server B are on a different network of the networks that are present on server B.

Giving an example, the IPs present for those cluster resources, was 192.168.10.11 one on the server A network, and one IP 192.168.50.11 assigned on server B.

Let me try to detail at best of my abilities:
When doing an ipconfig on Server B: as the IP 192.168.20.11, subnet mask 255.255.254.0, and gateway 192.168.30.1. The third octet of the gateway is different than the main IP address of the server.

When I tried to reassign new IPs for the cluster resources, I tried to assign IPs from the 192.168.20.x range, but it did not accept it.

When I pressed ok, those IPs are now shown as 0.0.0.0. If I go to cluster resource setting and try to change the ip again it only allows me to give IP address from the configured gateway range, 192.168.30.x.

So I'm guessing that there is one of two issues:

**a)** the main IP assigned to server B should be on the same range of the gateway, or
**b)** the gateway should be on the same network of the main IP.

Is it possible to have this configuration? To the best of my knowledge the servers were working fine, that is, until probably something bad happening to server A and trying to failover to server B and flag would be raised because of the cluster inability to failover.

Comment: You need to fail over the cluster IP address for the six resources. If there is no route for the cluster IP on the second server it will not work. Obviously a design problem, should we assume there's no test environment either?

Comment: Usually you define the networks in the failover cluster manager and then it automatically recognizes the network adapters and sets an ip. Why are you setting the ip directly?